# Inner Join not working to get lookup value

Tags: sql, vb6

Hi I have a table (called Assen) which has a lookup field in it (AsUnnits) to another table STS__Units.

In the Assen table you can select the dropdown in access to select 1 which shows as mm, 2 which shows as degrees, 3 which shows as inches, etc.

In my VB I have written a SQL statement to get this as a recordset but when this is returned it gives me the keys (ie 1,2,3) and not the values (mm, degrees, inches).

I therefore tried to add an inner join to the STS_Units Table but that doesnt seem to work.  Below is my SQL statement (sorry its abit long).  You will find the Units field Im trying to get at the bottom just before the FROM

```
SELECT
  Assen.ASnummer,
  Assen.ASScalingSnelheidEenheden,
  Assen.ASScalingSnelheidPulsen,
  Assen.ASScalingPositieEenheden,
  Assen.ASScalingPositiePulsen,
  Assen.ASScalingPositieResolutie,
  Assen.ASPositieMin,
  Assen.ASPositieMax,
  Assen.ASNoodAcc,
  Assen.ASStopAcc,
  Assen.ASLocalAcc,
  Assen.ASLocalSpeed,
  Assen.ASDefaultManAcc,
  Assen.ASDefaultManSpeed,
  Assen.ASPositieLimitLow,
  Assen.ASPositieLimitHigh,
  Assen.ASSpeedLimitLow,
  Assen.ASSpeedLimitHigh,
  Assen.ASAccLimitLow,
  Assen.ASAccLimitHigh,
  Assen.ASDeaccLimitLow,
  Assen.ASDeaccLimitHigh,
  Assen.ASDefaultAutoSpeed,
  Assen.ASDefaultAutoAcc,
  Assen.ASDefaultAutoDeacc,
  Assen.ASDirection,
  Assen.ASNetWerkNr,
  Assen.ASNodeNr,
  Assen.ASType,
  Assen.AsGotoQDistance,
  DecorLijst.DLNegDirection,
  DecorLijst.DLPosDirection,
  Assen.AsDecimaal,
  Assen.AsUnit
FROM (DecorLijst
INNER JOIN Assen
  ON DecorLijst.DLAsNr = Assen.ASnummer)
INNER JOIN STS_UnitTable
  ON Assen.ASUnit = STS_UnitTable.UTID
WHERE (((Assen.ASCueable) = TRUE))
ORDER BY Assen.ASnummer;
```

Comment: which sql database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pull the description from the STS_UnitTable. So, instead of

```
Assen.AsUnit
```

in the select list, you need to use

```
STS_UnitTable.ColumnName
```

using whatever the column name in STS_UnitTable that contains the descriptive names for the keys (mm, degrees, inches)

Comment: @SimonWait Glad I could help.